# Sum of exponential variables with decreasing means

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

### Problem

Let $Y_k$ be exponential indipendent random variables of parameter $\alpha k$ for $k\in \{1,2,...,n\}$, i.e. the CDF is $P(Y_k\le x)=1-e^{-\alpha k x}$

Prove that the CDF of
$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nY_k$$
is $$P(S_n\le y)=\left( 1-e^{-\alpha y}\right)^n$$

### My try: Induction

It's obvious for $n=1$. Let's suppose it's true for a certain $n$, then we have (I write "P" for probability, but in some cases I mean probability density):

$$P(S_{n+1}\le y)=P(S_n + Y_{n+1}\le y)= \int_0^{\infty}P(S_n\le y-Y_{n+1}, Y_{n+1}=x)dx = \int_0^{\infty} P(S_n\le y-x| Y_{n+1}=x)P(Y_{n+1}=x)dx$$

Because of the indipendece of the $Y_k$ and knowing the PDF of $Y_{n+1}$ and the CDF of $S_n$ we have

$$P(S_{n+1}\le y)= \int_0^{\infty} \left( 1-e^{-\alpha (y-x)}\right)^n\alpha(n+1)e^{-\alpha(n+1)x} dx = \int_0^{\infty} \alpha(n+1)\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(-1)^ie^{-i\alpha(y-x)}e^{-\alpha(n+1)x}dx = \alpha(n+1)\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} e^{-i\alpha y}(-1)^i \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x(n+1-i)}dx = \alpha(n+1)\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i} e^{-i\alpha y}(-1)^i \dfrac{1}{\alpha(n+1-i)} = \sum_{i=0}^n (-e^{-\alpha y})^i\dfrac{n+1}{n+1-i}\cdot \dfrac{n!}{i!(n-i)!} = \sum_{i=0}^n (-e^{-\alpha y})^i \binom{n+1}{i}$$

If the sum was from $0$ to $n+1$ this would be correct, but it's not.

What did I do wrong and do you know other ways to prove this theorem?

---

EDIT: found my mistake, the integral should be from $0$ to $y$ because
$$P(S_n\le y)=0$$ if $y<0$.

I would still be curious about a way to solve this problem without induction, i.e. without knowing the solution beforehand.

Comment: characteristic function of sum = product of characteristic functions for each variable in the sum

Comment: @kevinkayaks I found the chararcteristic function: $$\phi(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n\dfrac{\alpha k}{\alpha k-t}$$ but I don't know how o calculate the CDF. The PDF should be the Fourier transform, but I don't know how to calculate the Fourier transform of this product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know the solution beforehand to use induction. First compute the distribution of $S_2$ by convolution:
$$
f_{S_2}(t) = (f_{Y_1}\star f_{Y_2})(t) = \int_0^t \alpha e^{-\alpha s}2\alpha e^{-2\alpha(t-s)}\ \mathsf ds = 2\alpha e^{-\alpha t}(1-e^{-\alpha t}).
$$
Integrating yields
$$
F_{S_2}(t) = \int_0^t 2\alpha e^{-\alpha s}(1-e^{-\alpha s)}\ \mathsf ds = (1-e^{-\alpha t})^2.
$$
Computing $F_{S_n}(t)$ for a few more values of $n$ would suggest the pattern $F_{S_n}(t) = (1-e^{-\alpha t})^n$, and seeing as this is true for $n=1$, assuming it to be true for some $n\geqslant 1$ we compute the density of $S_{n+1}$ by
\begin{align}
f_{S_{n+1}}&=(f_{S_n}\star f_{Y_{n+1}})(t)\\ &= \int_0^t n\alpha e^{-\alpha s}(1-e^{-\alpha s})^{n-1}(n+1)\alpha e^{-(n+1)\alpha (t-s)}\ \mathsf ds \\
&=(n+1)\alpha e^{-\alpha t}(1-e^{-\alpha t} )^n.
\end{align}
Integrating yields $F_{S_{n+1}}(t) = (1-e^{-\alpha t})^{n+1}$, which concludes the proof.